# trouble with configuring scala project in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have been following the [getting started with IntelliJ and Scala video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJe4wPUtcUQ) from JetBrains and running into two problems.

1. I can't get it create or start a run configuration
2. I don't see the scala-test library as a selection under ProjectStructure-Modules-ChooseLibraries

What I've done so far is

1. Install Scala, add path and environment variables
2. Install Scala intellij plugin
3. Create new project set project sdk to java 1.7 and scala home to /usr/local/share/scala-2.10.3
4. Create an object that extends from App with a simple write line:
   [image]

The one source file object

```
  object HelloWorld{
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println("hello")
    }
  }
```

In the video they right click on the object file and can see a selection of run, but in my case I only see run as Scala Console.  I can't seem to get the debugger to work and when I try to create a run configuration as an "Application" it says the src file is "not acceptable"

[image]

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ are you using? IntelliJ will not always mark the scala folder as source folder correctly (source root should be blue in the project view), and the maven plugin may cause it to be unmarked. Another known bug would be IntelliJ picking the incorrect scala path for the facet. Check the project settings and Facets -> Scala, it might incorrectly be set to to <scalaHome>/bin.

Comment: It's the latest version 13.  I tried it again on my home computer and it worked, so the only difference I can tell is that in the one that works I'm setting the scala home to the home brew suggested /usr/local/opt/scala/idea , wheras on the other machine I didn't install scala using homebrew and instead linked directly to the downloaded scala folder in downloads... I'll check the computer at work again and see if its pointing to the bin folder.

Comment: Since you mention homebrew, I assume you use OS X?

Comment: yes, latest install of os x on a brand new from the factory macbook pro.

Comment: I reinstalled scala using the same homebrew install and setup a project setting scala home to /usr/local/opt/scala/idea, same as my home machine but no luck.

Comment: so it says cannot access HelloWorld in com.hello.HelloWorld when i try to manually type in the main class in the run configuration... even though it actually does work when I execute.

Comment: I have the same problem with Idea 14, everything is fine, but "unacceptable" when I try to run it as an App and no option to just run it in the right-click menu either.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend my simple project [skeleton](http://github.com/fractal/skeleton), to get you quickly up and running with Intellij, SBT and even Eclipse setup. Hope it helps!